# Loop results of procedure execution in pl/sql

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql

I want to make stored procedure which going to check Oracle db tables and do statistics gathering for them. 
I have made this so far, and I would like to now how can I catch a result of execution for each line in a same loop?

```
declare

    comm varchar2(200);

    cursor c1 is 
    select owner, table_name, num_rows, last_analyzed  from dba_tables
    where num_rows>=500000
    and owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM')
    and last_analyzed <= sysdate -7
    order by 3 desc;


begin
    FOR V1 IN C1 LOOP

    comm:= 'EXEC DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats( '''||V1.OWNER||''','''||V1.TABLE_NAME||''' , estimate_percent => DBMS_STATS.auto_sample_size);';

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE comm;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: You can try to use EXECUTE IMMEDIATE comm RETURNING field1 INTO v_field1.;

Comment: What value are you expecting that statement to return?

Comment: Also, EXEC is a SQL\*Plus call: `execute immediate` won't like it. You need to frame the call as an anonymous PL/SQL block: `begin dbms_stats.gather_table_stats( ...); end;`

Comment: I would like to have for every Execute immediate line output like: PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Comment: You don’t need any dynamic code to do this. Just call `dbms_stats.gather_table_stats` the same way you would call any other procedure.

Comment: Mounting soapbox! Just curious but why sort the tables. Does it really make any difference forcing stats on a table not analyzed for 3 weeks before one not analyzed for 2 weeks. They're both going to be done in the same run of the script. Just one of my idiosyncrasies "don't sort if it doesn't make any difference". Oh well, getting off soapbox.

Answer (score 0):

From a purely syntactical perspective, your code could be something like this:

```
begin
    for r in (
        select t.owner, t.table_name, t.num_rows
        from   dba_tables t
               left join dba_external_tables x
                    on  x.owner = t.owner and x.table_name = t.table_name
        where  t.owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM')
        and    t.temporary = 'N'
        and    x.table_name is null
        and    t.num_rows >= 500000
        and    t.last_analyzed <= sysdate -7
    )
    loop
        begin
            dbms_stats.gather_table_stats(r.owner, r.table_name);
        exception
            when others then
                dbms_output.put_line('Error gathering stats on table '|| r.owner||'.'||r.table_name||': '|| sqlerrm);
        end;
    end loop;
end;
```

I have excluded external and temporary tables, and failures are skipped.

However, I'm not sure this is a good approach.

Are you sure you want to gather stats for every table in every other schema?

What should happen with tables that don't have any stats?

Are you sure you want to use the default `method_opt` setting for every table? Some tables might have carefully crafted histograms and extended statistics column groups, or they might deliberately avoid histograms altogether.

Could there be tables with huge volumes that will take many hours to process? If so, are you ready for your script to run for several days?

Answer (score -1):

I tried and this will do for now.... Thank you for your replies

```
declare

    comm varchar2(200);


    cursor c1 is 
select owner, table_name, num_rows, last_analyzed  from dba_tables
where num_rows>=500000
and owner not in ('SYS','SYSTEM')
and last_analyzed <= sysdate -7
order by 3 desc;


begin
    FOR V1 IN C1 LOOP
    begin
      comm := 'begin DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats( '''||V1.OWNER||''','''||V1.TABLE_NAME||''' , estimate_percent => DBMS_STATS.auto_sample_size); end;';
      --dbms_output.put_line('begin DBMS_STATS.gather_table_stats( '''||V1.OWNER||''' , '''||V1.TABLE_NAME||''' , estimate_percent => DBMS_STATS.auto_sample_size); end;') ;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE comm ;
    dbms_output.put_line( V1.TABLE_NAME || '------Ok------') ;
    exception 
    when others then 
    dbms_output.put_line(V1.TABLE_NAME || '------Not ok------' || 'SQLERRM: '|| SQLERRM || ' Format error stack : '||dbms_utility.format_error_stack) ;
    end;
    end loop;
end;
```

Comment: What about tables that have have no stats (num_rows and last_analyzed are null)? Do you really want stats on temporary and external tables? Why are you using `execute immediate` instead of just calling `dbms_stats` normally, the way you already call `dbms_output`?